# Missing argument for "base" encrypt 4.1.0 flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, package

I am trying to use the package encrypt 4.1. for flutter and I am getting the following error in the terminal when I try to run this command
`secure-random -b`
the output is the following:

````
FormatException: Missing argument for "base".
#0      Parser.validate (package:args/src/parser.dart:290:21)
#1      Parser.readNextArgAsValue (package:args/src/parser.dart:114:5)
#2      Parser.parseSoloOption (package:args/src/parser.dart:145:7)
#3      Parser.parse (package:args/src/parser.dart:86:11)
#4      ArgParser.parse (package:args/src/arg_parser.dart:326:42)
#5      main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/encrypt-4.1.0/bin/secure-random.dart:18:29)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Missing argument for "base".
#0      Parser.validate (package:args/src/parser.dart:290:21)
#1      Parser.readNextArgAsValue (package:args/src/parser.dart:114:5)
#2      Parser.parseSoloOption (package:args/src/parser.dart:145:7)
#3      Parser.parse (package:args/src/parser.dart:86:11)
#4      ArgParser.parse (package:args/src/arg_parser.dart:326:42)
#5      main (file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/encrypt-4.1.0/bin/secure-random.dart:18:29)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)```
I have dart-sdk/bin into the environment variables,does anyone know why and how to solve it?
````